# CherryPy AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'unquote _to_bytes'

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to use cherryPy but while accessing the webpage the following error is displayed : `AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'unquote_to_bytes'`. I have checked the module six.moves urllib_parse has the attribute named unquote_to_bytes, but still cherrypy shows this error. The server starts normally but this error is only shown when accessing the webpage by typing the url. Below is the code copied from cherrypy basic tutorial just modified with the IP and port number:

```
import cherrypy
import globals


class HelloWorld(object):
   @cherrypy.expose
   def index(self):
     return "Hello World!"


cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': "192.168.10.11",
                    'server.socket_port': 8088,
                    })
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

This is the actual traceback:

```
[04/Feb/2019:20:26:23] ENGINE
AttributeError("'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'unquote_to_bytes'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1242, in communicate req.parse_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cheroot/server.py", line  712, in parse_request
success = self.read_request_line()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cheroot/server.py", line  912, in read_request_line for x in QUOTED_SLASH_REGEX.split(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cheroot/server.py", line  912, in <listcomp> for x in QUOTED_SLASH_REGEX.split(path)AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'unquote
_to_bytes'
```

Comment: I would try put the port as a string

Comment: @chris CherryPy needs integer for port number.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar error, and noticed that currently CherryPy and cheroot versions do play a big role.

I did my fix as follows:

```
pip uninstall CherryPy

pip install --force-reinstall CherryPy==18.1.0

pip uninstall cheroot

pip install --force-reinstall cheroot==6.5.4
```

I do hope this works for you as well.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks @MrMaavin - yes, this was exactly the format I was looking for yesterday - (what did I learn.. do not try to answer StackOverflow with a toddler around...:)

Comment: thank you; I got this error trying to use [`web.py`](https://webpy.org/) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS